# Semantic UI: Password validation with regex

Tags: regex, semantic-ui

I am trying to write a password validation rule in Semantic UI using regex. The validation rule should comply with the following:

1. Password cannot contain `&` symbol
2. Allowed special chars for password are: `!@#$%*-_=+`

I wrote the rule as below:

```
{
    type   : 'regExp[/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*-_=+]*[^&]*$/]',
    prompt : 'Please enter appropriate password'
}
```

It does not fire up the the prompt message even after using `&` in the password, which should have not happened.

Comment: Although `*-_` creates a broad range between `*` and `_` chars in the ASCII table, it does not include `&`. You might want to use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*_=+-]*$/` but it seems [`^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*-_=+]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/FZibPA/2) does not allow `&` either.

Comment: I have checked with this tester: https://regex101.com/. My regex does not accept strings with '&', but does not fire up the the prompt message even after using '&' in the password, which should have not happened.

Comment: Strange, examples suggest `type   : 'regExp[/^[a-z0-9!@#$%*_=+-]/i]',`, but the docs say `type   : 'regExp[/^[a-z0-9!@#$%*_=+-]/i]]',`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a Semantic UI page, it seems that the rule should be
triggered if the password is *invalid*, containing an illegal character.
The given regex is intended to match *valid* passwords:

```
type   : 'regExp[/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*-_=+]*[^&]*$/]',
```

(It won’t quite do so, but that seems to be what you were aiming for.)

What we want to do is match *any single illegal character*:

```
type   : 'regExp[/[^-a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*_=+]/]',
```

If the password is valid, the regex will fail and the rule will not be
triggered. If there are any illegal characters, the regex will match and
the rule will activate.

The hyphen has been moved to the beginning to avoid forming an
unintended range.